# InDesign Script to Populate Rectangle BG Color Codes into TextBox

Tags: javascript, automation, adobe, background-color, adobe-indesign

I mostly work on creating Brand guidelines using InDesign where I have to add multiple brand colors. Each color is shown on a page as a rectangle background and a text box that shows the color codes with its Hex, RGB, and CMYK code.

It gets quite hectic as I have mostly 10-30 colors and manually does all these for each color.

[image: Color Codes of the rectangle bg]

I'm new to Javascript but somehow managed to get some color codes using JSX with the help of ChatGPT but I can't get CMYK color if the document type is RGB and if the document type is CMYK then I'm unable to get RGB.

I'm only interested in the color values present on the color picker and I know depending on the document type CMYK values might be different but that doesn't matter as of now.

***Working on it on Windows PC so no Applescript option :(.***

Here is my current code:

```
if (app.selection.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < app.selection.length; i++) {
    var selectedObject = app.selection[i];

    if (selectedObject instanceof Rectangle && selectedObject.fillColor !== null) {
      var fillColor = selectedObject.fillColor;

      if (fillColor.space === ColorSpace.RGB) {
        var hexCode = getHexCode(fillColor);
        var rgbCode = getRGBCode(fillColor);
        var cmykCode = "N/A"; // CMYK not applicable for RGB colors
        
        createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode);
      } else if (fillColor.space === ColorSpace.CMYK) {
        var hexCode = "N/A"; // Hex not applicable for CMYK colors
        var rgbCode = getRGBCode(fillColor);
        var cmykCode = getCMYKCode(fillColor);
        
        createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode);
      }
    }
  }
}

function createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode) {
  var frameWidth = 280; // Width of the text frame
  var frameHeight = 120; // Height of the text frame
  
  var topMargin = 40; // Top margin
  var leftMargin = 40; // Left margin

  // Calculate the coordinates for the bounding box
  var boundingBox = [
    selectedObject.geometricBounds[0] + topMargin, // Top position with margin
    selectedObject.geometricBounds[1] + leftMargin, // Left position with margin
    selectedObject.geometricBounds[0] + topMargin + frameHeight, // Bottom position with margin
    selectedObject.geometricBounds[1] + leftMargin + frameWidth // Right position with margin
  ];

  var textFrame = selectedObject.parentPage.textFrames.add({
    geometricBounds: boundingBox,
    contents: "RGB: " + rgbCode + "\nCMYK: " + cmykCode + "\nHex: " + hexCode,
    textFramePreferences: {
      autoSizingType: AutoSizingTypeEnum.OFF
    }
  });

  textFrame.fillColor = "None";
  textFrame.strokeColor = "None";

  var basicParagraphStyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.itemByName("Basic Paragraph");

  if (basicParagraphStyle.isValid) {
    textFrame.paragraphs.everyItem().appliedParagraphStyle = basicParagraphStyle;
  }

  textFrame.textFramePreferences.verticalJustification = VerticalJustification.CENTER_ALIGN;
}

function getHexCode(color) {
  var colorValues = color.colorValue;
  var hexCode = "#" + decimalToHex(colorValues[0]) + decimalToHex(colorValues[1]) + decimalToHex(colorValues[2]);
  return hexCode;
}

function decimalToHex(decimal) {
  var hex = Math.round(decimal).toString(16);
  return hex.length === 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function getRGBCode(color) {
  var colorValues = color.colorValue;
  var rgbCode = Math.round(colorValues[0]) + ", " + Math.round(colorValues[1]) + ", " + Math.round(colorValues[2]);
  return rgbCode;
}

function getCMYKCode(color) {
  var colorValues = color.colorValue;
  var cmykCode = colorValues[0] + "%, " + colorValues[1] + "%, " + colorValues[2] + "%, " + colorValues[3] + "%";
  return cmykCode;
}
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing the issue.

Comment: The following AppleScript will change the color space and have InDesign convert the colors.
```
    tell application "Adobe InDesign 2023" to set space of fill color of selection to CMYK
```
Perhaps ExtendScript can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can create the temp color with the same values, convert it into any space (CMYK or RGB) and then get the numbers from this temp color:

```
// create the temp color with the same properties as 'fillColor'
var temp_color = app.activeDocument.colors.add({
  name:       fillColor.name + '_temp',
  colorValue: fillColor.colorValue,
  space:      fillColor.space,
});

if (fillColor.space === ColorSpace.RGB) {
  var hexCode = getHexCode(fillColor);
  var rgbCode = getRGBCode(fillColor);
  temp_color.space = ColorSpace.CMYK;      // convert the temp color into CMYK
  var cmykCode = getCMYKCode(temp_color);  // get the numbers
  createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode);
}
else if (fillColor.space === ColorSpace.CMYK) {
  temp_color.space = ColorSpace.RGB;       // convert the temp color into RGB
  var hexCode = getHexCode(temp_color);    // get the numbers
  var rgbCode = getRGBCode(temp_color);    // get the numbers
  var cmykCode = getCMYKCode(fillColor);
  createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode);
}

temp_color.remove(); // remove the temp color
```

Or you can replace the the code above with these lines:

```
// get the properties from 'fillColor'
var temp_color_properties = fillColor.properties;

// create the temp CMYK color
temp_color_properties.name = fillColor.name + '_temp_cmyk';
var temp_cmyk_color = app.activeDocument.colors.add(temp_color_properties);
temp_cmyk_color.space = ColorSpace.CMYK;

// create the temp RGB color
temp_color_properties.name = fillColor.name + '_temp_rgb';
var temp_rgb_color = app.activeDocument.colors.add(temp_color_properties);
temp_rgb_color.space = ColorSpace.RGB;

// get the numbers
var hexCode  = getHexCode(temp_rgb_color);
var rgbCode  = getRGBCode(temp_rgb_color);
var cmykCode = getCMYKCode(temp_cmyk_color);

// remove the temp colors
temp_cmyk_color.remove();
temp_rgb_color.remove();

createColorCodeTextFrame(selectedObject, hexCode, rgbCode, cmykCode);
```

And probably you need to add `Math.round()` to CMYK values as well as it's done for RGB values.

Results:

[image]

**Update.** The script uses current measuring units of the document. So if you're using inches it can get you the weird results like this:

[image]

You can temporary change units to pixels with these lines at the start of your code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var orig_x_units = doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits;
var orig_y_units = doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits;
doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.PIXELS;
doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.PIXELS;
```

And then change the units back to orinal with these lines at the end of your script:

```
doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = orig_x_units;
doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = orig_y_units;
```

Comment: Thanks, Yuri. Works perfectly for a Web document but it doesn't work if I have a print document. Although I see _temp swatches created and deleted but nothing else. I don't see any text frame.

Comment: I just tried my code again on a Web and on a Print document (macOS, InDesign v.17.4.) and it works just fine. I added the screenshot into my answer. Here is the full script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FEY9iqgqb64K3kJe8W30raou3rXExuuj/view?usp=sharing Try it.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. Unfortunately, it isn't working for me when used with the print document on my InDesign 18.2 (Windows 11). Although I see swatches being created and deleted with no result otherwise. For the web document, everything works perfectly but when I use it with a Print document it does nothing no warning or any textbox appearing. Nevertheless, my workflow mostly includes the Web document so it will help me with that.

Comment: The only thing I can think is the measuring units. Do you use inches? Since this script uses current units as is, and for web documents they are pixels or points usually. It gets you correct size and position of the textboxes. But if a pirnt document uses inches it will get you very big textboxes somewhere far away from the page.

Comment: I just added the new screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the exact issue. It was far away and not even visible despite fully zooming out. I found it through layer panels. Is there any way to restrict the textbox to just within the rectangle?

Comment: If you're happy with the way how it works with your web documents probably all you need is temporary to change the units to Points (or Pixels), run the script, and then change the units back. Of course it can be done within the script. But first try to do it manually and let me know if it works well.

Comment: Yup. Works perfectly when I change the units to pixels.

Comment: I've added the couple of snippets how it can be done in the script. And btw, you can change the units on the fly, if you press **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+U** (on Windows) one or several times.